# Nodejs File Search from Array of Filenames

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, search, filenames

I am attempting to do a file search based off array of file names and root directory.  I found some file search snips online that seem to work when I am finding just 1 single file, but it will not work when there is more than 1 file specified.  Below is the snippet:

```html
const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path');
var dir = '<SOME ROOT DIRECTORY>';
var file = 'Hello_World.txt'
var fileArr = ['Hello_World.txt', 'Hello_World2.txt', 'Hello_World3.txt'];

const findFile = function (dir, pattern) {
    var results = [];
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function (dirInner) {
        dirInner = path.resolve(dir, dirInner);
        var stat = fs.statSync(dirInner);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            results = results.concat(findFile(dirInner, pattern));
        }
        if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
            results.push(dirInner);
        }
    });
    return results;
};

console.log(findFile(dir, file));
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working with an array rather than just a single file string?

Doing the following seems to be working, but didn't know if there were other ways to do this which may be simpler:

```html
newFileArr = [];

fileArr.forEach((file => {
    //findFile(dir, file).toString();
    console.log(findFile(dir, file).toString());
}));
```

Comment: `patterns.indexOf(dirInner) ??
or patterns.some(pattern => dirInner.endsWith(pattern))`

Comment: you are doing correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that needs to change is the condition to determine if an individual filepath meets the search criteria. In the code you've posted, it looks like `dirInner.endsWith(pattern)`, which says "does the filepath end with the given pattern?"

We want to change that to say "does the filepath end with *any* of the given patterns?" And closer to how the code will look, we can rephrase that as "Can we find a given pattern such that the filepath ends with that pattern?"

Let's rename `pattern` to `patterns`. Then we can simple replace `dirInner.endsWith(patterns)` with `patterns.some(pattern => dirInner.endsWith(pattern))`

Comment: Excellent, let me work with this for a few...Thanks!